# Should the cookie warning be updated to include a clickable link?

Tags: bug, status-completed, banner

I just got a cookie warning in the lower-left of the page when I visited https://stackoverflow.com/. However, it shows a link as it would appear in Markdown, not in the properly rendered HTML.

[image]

Can I assume this is unintentional? If so, please consider this question as a bug report.

Comment: Already reported on MSE: [Cookie-policy link in popup shows raw Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362703/289905).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

We were able to get this fixed up in our last build and seems to be back to how it should be. We even fixed the period to be outside the link instead of inside - that's what you were reporting... right?

[image: Screenshot of the new cookie banner with the markdown fixed]